# Stop a thief in Vanilla Minecraft: Detect if player is x distance from y,z coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to catch a thief in 1.19 Minecraft. I had one set of commands to see if items were taken out of a chest, but that was defeated -- I suspect they used X-ray hacked client to disable the command block:

```
/execute if block -109 63 208 chest{Items:[]} say @p is a thief
```

I want to duplicate the trap but also output to logs if they try to mine the command block again.  I thought I could use this to see if they were too close:

```
/execute if entity @a[distance=..10] say @p is a vandal
```

but then realized if they have Xray, they can see the 2nd command block, suspect something was up, and avoid triggering the trap. I want to hide the 2nd block far away, so they only see the original command block

So I need a command to say

```
/execute if entity @a[distance_from_coords=..5| 102 59 210] say @p is a vandal
```

(an entity got within 5 blocks of the 1st command block)

Is there any way to do this, or otherwise clever way to catch the thief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `x=`, `y=`, and `z=` to specify the location to calculate distance from:

```
@a[x=102,y=59,z=210,distance=..5]
```

This checks that the distance between the player and *the specified coordinates* is less than five blocks.

Comment: Aha! Thank you!